# Android Stellar SDK throwing NullPointerException on KeyStore.aliases() in Crashlytics reports

Tags: stellar-sdk, android

Crashlytics report for my android app shows that a considerable number of my users are getting the following null pointer exception. Most of my users who get this error are on **Android 6**. It happens only when the build is **obfuscated**.

The crash is caused by a call to,

```
org.stellar.sdk.Server(String uri)
```

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
 'java.util.Enumeration java.security.KeyStore.aliases()' on a null object reference
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.acceptedIssuers(TrustManagerImpl.java:185)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getAcceptedIssuers(TrustManagerImpl.java:603)
 at shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.buildTrustRootIndex(Platform.java)
 at shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.afterHandshake(Platform.java)
 at shadow.okhttp3.internal.tls.CertificateChainCleaner.get(CertificateChainCleaner.java:8)
 at shadow.okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:8)
 at shadow.okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:7)
 at org.stellar.sdk.Server.<init>(Server.java:7)
 at com.myapp.MyStellarManager.<clinit>(MyStellarManager.java)
 at com.myapp.MainVM$observableData$1.invokeSuspend(MainVM.java:2)
 at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(Intrinsics.java)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:2)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$getCorePoolSize$p(CoroutineScheduler.java)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.java:18)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:18)
```

Comment: I note you have this question also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642943/getting-nullpointerexception-on-keystore-aliases-in-crashlytics-reports-for-an  - That is a much better place for it, as it is almost certainly not something Stellar related. Where did you find the android SDK? Is it https://github.com/kinecosystem/android-stellar-sdk/tree/master/android-stellar-sdk ?

Comment: @Synesso I created a fork from https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk. Should I be using kinecosystem fork?

Comment: I don't know about that fork. I only googled for it. I've created a PR with an upgraded okhttp. You might want to try building it locally to see if that helps. https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/pull/269